# kubernetes, have 2 replicas of the pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a front end app on a POD called. Right now, when I deploy and the POD rebuilds, the site content on that PODF will be some minutes down, it will be down all the time that takes to the POD to rebuild, so I need to create a replica of the POD for:

- the one which is active and will be available for users while the new one:
- a new one that is creating and will replace the active one.

Currently I have this values in my config:

```
strategy:
  rollingUpdate:
    maxSurge: 1
    maxUnavailable: 1
```

What should I change for have those 2 replicas?

`maxUnavailable` should be 0?

What else? I couldn't find much info about how to have 2 replicas.

Comment: You are looking for the concept of a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

Comment: @DanielMann thanks, I'm pretty new to Kubernetes, I was watching a video of "ReplicaSets and Deployments". I will read the documentation with patience (sadly I have to complete this task tomorrow haha)

Answer (score 0):

In the rolling update, you have the two variables:

- maxSurge: The number of pods that can be created above the desired amount of pods during an update
- maxUnavailable: The number of pods that can be unavailable during the update process

So if you want to keep (the number of available replicas >= the replicas count) at any given moment, you can set `maxUnavailable` to 0.